# How can I figure out what my apartment ethernet jacks are connected to?

Tags: networking, home-networking

I recently moved into a new apartment and am trying to get the ethernet ports in each of the rooms working. I suspect they are all wired to the same hub or switch, however when I try and ping statically configured machines in different rooms I do not receive a reply. Furthermore the LEDS on the devices being connected do not light up as they usually do (I assume this has something to do with the absence of power on the ethernet lines, but I'm not sure if this is necessary or how it normally works, I suspect that the hub/switch normally provides power). I found a panel which appears to contain five stripped ethernet cables hooked up to a box and believe this is some kind of hub (though I don't see how it would be powered) which facilitates communication between the different jacks. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Image: (don't have the reputation to include it in post yet)]

Comment: Are you sure these are for ethernet? UTP is used for many things, including POTS. It may be that they aren't connected to anything in particular, and you can use them for various applications.

Comment: That's not even a hub, looks more like a [punchdown block](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punch-down_block) for easily connecting wires. All it can do is connect the ends of two cables, not all the ports together.

Comment: Why not to call apartment management or your ISP provider? This patch panel doesn't looks like it connected to something

Comment: make sure you actually are paying for internet service and you are physically connected. Also if ityour are subscribed, your pings might be dropped by a firewall

Answer (score 2):

Your picture of the punch-down block shows that they're not connected to anything. They're terminated on the backside of that punch-down block, but nothing's punched down on the front, thus no connection.